# Media Streaming - Media Streaming through a Session Initiated Protocol (SIP) (Intellectual Ventures) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, us20140059238a1, intellectual-ventures

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON streaming media through a session initiation protocol** - This application from [Intellectual Ventures](http://www.intellectualventures.com/) seeks to patent the idea of...Sending a first session initiation protocol (SIP) message from a first device to a second device, receiving a second SIP message from the second device at the first device, sending a third SIP message from the first device to the second device, and receiving the requested media stream from the second device at the first device.! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 12/30/2002** that discusses:

> - Streaming media based on streaming parameters

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - The streaming parameters may include range, scale, speed, **a length of the requested media stream**, etc.

**TITLE: Session initiation Protocol for media streaming**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Sending a **first session initiation protocol (SIP) message** from a **first device** to a **second device**, a **first header field** of the **first SIP message** includes a **first indicator** indicating a request for a **media stream** and a source of the requested **media stream**, receiving a **second SIP message** from the **second device** at the **first device**, a **second header field** of the **second SIP message** includes a **second indicator** indicating acceptance of the request for the **media stream**, sending a **third SIP message** from the **first device** to the **second device**, a **third header field** of the **third SIP message** includes a **third indicator** indicating that the **second device** initiate streaming of the requested **media stream**, and receiving the requested **media stream** from the **second device** at the **first device**.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20140059238 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140059238)
- **Application Number**: US 14/069,817
- **Assignee**: Intellectual Ventures
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 12/30/2002
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 8/26/2014
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20140059238#c=0&d1=12%2F30%2F2002)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1. sending a first session invitation protocol (SIP) message from a first device to a second device, wherein a first header field of the first SIP message includes a first indicator indicating a request for a media stream and a source of the requested media stream;
> 2. receiving a second SIP message from the second device at the first device, wherein a second header field of the second SIP message includes a second indicator indicating acceptance of the request for the media stream;
> 3. sending a third SIP message from the first device to the second device, wherein a third header field of the third SIP message includes a third indicator indicating that the second device initiate streaming of the requested media stream; and
> 4. receiving the requested media stream from the second device at the first device.

In English this means:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1a. Sending a first session initiation protocol (SIP) message from a first device to a second device,
>
> 1b. A first header field of the first SIP message includes a first indicator indicating a request for a media stream and a source of the requested media stream;
>
> 2a. Receiving a second SIP message from the second device at the first device,
>
> 2b. A second header field of the second SIP message includes a second indicator indicating acceptance of the request for the media stream;
>
> 3a. Sending a third SIP message from the first device to the second device,
>
> 3b. A third header field of the third SIP message includes a third indicator indicating that the second device initiate streaming of the requested media stream; and
>
> 4. Receiving the requested media stream from the second device at the first device.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 12/30/2002

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming Receiving a third SIP message at the first device from the second device, wherein the third SIP message includes streaming parameters for the requested media stream

---

**"Streaming Media through a session initiation protocol messages" from the Applicant**
[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: Please do not use short-form middle-endian date style. It is extremely confusing to readers from the vast majority of the world. Either use YYYY-MM-DD, or spell out the month name in full.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of potential prior art for this patent application: [US6965614](https://www.google.com/patents/US6965614?dq=6965614&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q9M6U538F6rUsAS96YDwCQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA)

This US patent describes the use of SIP in media streaming and also discusses the process of server-user requests interchange using SIP.

If you are aware of other potential prior art references, please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another potential prior art for this request: [EP1247387](https://www.google.com/patents/EP1247387B1?cl=en&dq=ep1247387&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KZpGU_2-J8Lf0gGy6ICYDg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA)

This European patent is entitled Improved session initiation protocol (SIP). This patent appears to describing the use of SIP in media streaming, as listed in claim 1.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this describes what RealVideo was going back in the 90s

[This excerpt](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/fire/ch15_07.htm) from O'Reilly's Building Internet Firewalls Second Edition [which was released in June 2000](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565928718.do) describes the handshake which happens before the stream is initiated

The table on this page describes the requests back and forth, and the part which mentions session initiation is...

> RealAudio and RealVideo by default use a system where a TCP
>   connection, initiated by the client, is used for session control,
>   while the actual data is transferred using UDP.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search found this URL
http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Fun_Numbers

It contains a specific sip number: sip:*266305@ekiga.net    Blueface Music (Ireland)

This seems to be part of the Ekiga sip network .

You can call the number to get streaming music.

A similar url can be found here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Phone+Numbers

It also contains a number to call and get music.

Comment: The date in a prior art request is very important as something which is common today may have been novel at the time of the patent filing -- the question ask for material dated BEFORE 12/30/2002 -- does your link contains verifiable dated material from before that date?